# Let with Linq saves double enumeration instead of using extension method style

Tags: c#, linq

Will the first query be more often enumerated due to the double .Select() and does the let operator eliminate really the double enumeration?

```
var y = product.Documents
.Where(p => p.Type == "test_DOC")
.Select(p => GetPathToLabel(p.Name))
.Select(path => FileExists(path) ? File.ReadAllBytes(path) : null)
.Where(data => data != null)
.ToList();

var x = (from p in product.Documents
     where p.Type == "test_DOC"
     let path = GetPathToLabel(p.Name)
     let data = FileExists(path) ? File.ReadAllBytes(path) : null
     where data != null
     select data).ToList();
```

Comment: Add a `Where(FileExists)` after the first select to prevent you having to `Select` all items followed by `Where`ing anyway.

Comment: A double select just means that two selectors (methods) will be called for each item that is iterated. It does not affect iteration itself. For example, if you insert a `.Take(5)` before `.ToList()`, those selectors will only be called for the first 5 items. `Select(A).Select(B)` roughly amounts to `B(A(item))`. I assume the `let` keyword parts are combined into a single method, e.g. a single `.Select(p => { var path = GetPathToLabel(p.Name); return FileExists(path) ? File.ReadAllBytes(path) : null; })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Select` does not enumerate the query - only iterating with `foreach` or hydrating to a collection with `ToList` or `ToArray` will actually execute the query.  So no, you are not enumerating the collection twice.